# Button colour not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Problem-
Button colour is not changing,
I used jquery click function

```
<button class="red"  id="MyQuotes" href="#" title="">@Aceo.Crm.App.Resources.Shared.Order.Link_MyQuote</button>
```

For this button i used jquery as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#MyQuotes").click(function(){
    $(this).css({background:"red"});
    });
});
```

But it was not successfull, I tried to do this in this way too-

```
<button class="red" onclick="D()" id="MyQuotes" href="#" title="">@Aceo.Crm.App.Resources.Shared.Order.Link_MyQuote</button>
```

I made javascript function here as-

```
<script language="javascript">
function D()
{
document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";
}
</script>
```

And yes this time i was again failed.
Can you please suggest me some codes?

Comment: Hey Manoj, Welcome to SO. Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net of this so we could see, and modify from that?

Comment: Okay, i will make a fiddle

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/DrWjq/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#MyQuotes").click(function(){
    $(this).css({background:"red"});
   });
});
```

Pure JS: http://jsfiddle.net/wx9tw/

```
function D(id)
{
 id.style.backgroundColor="red";
}

<button class="red" onclick="D(this)" id="MyQuotes" href="#" title="">@Aceo.Crm.App.Resources.Shared.Order.Link_MyQuote</button>
```

Comment: This is not happening, it only gives flash to red color and nothing else

Comment: My mistake, selector's id is "#Myquotes", but didn't get need.

Answer (score 1):

your selector's id is "MyQuotes" and not "MyOrders"

try this

```
$("#MyQuotes").click(function(){
  $(this).css({background:"red"});
});
```

**OR**

```
function D()
{
  $('#MyQuotes').css({background:"red"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must refer the button (SO #MyQuotes not #MyOrders) in JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#MyQuotes").click(function(){
    $(this).css({background:"red"});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(this).css("background-color","red");` (and target the correct element id)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bmGa/)